# When $n>1$, there is no ordering $<$ on $\mathbb{Z_n}$ such that...

Tags: abstract-algebra, modular-arithmetic, order-theory

When $n>1$, there is no ordering $<$ on $\mathbb{Z_n}$ such that:

1. for all $[a]_n,[b]_n\in\mathbb{Z_n}$, we have exactly one of $[a]_n<[b]_n,[a]_n=[b]_n,$ or $[b]_n<[a]_n$;
2. if $[a]_n<[b]_n$ and $[b]_n<[c]_n$, then $[a]_n<[c]_n$; and
3. if $[a]_n<[b]_n$, then $[a]_n\oplus[c]_n<[b]_n\oplus[c]_n$ for each $[c]_n\in\mathbb{Z_n}$.

Proof: Let $n\in\mathbb{Z}$ with $n>1$.  Assume for contradiction that $<$ is an ordering on $\mathbb{Z_n}$ that satisfies (1), (2), (3) as listed above. Consider the two cases $[1]_n<[0]_n$ or $[0]_n<[1]_n$. These are the only cases because $[0]_n$ and $[1]_n$ are not equal to each other, so either $[1]_n<[0]_n$ or $[0]_n<[1]_n$.

- Case 1: Let $[1]_n<[0]_n$. Then by (3), we have $[k-1]_n<...<[2]_n<[1]_n<[0]_n$. Then by (2), we have $[k-1]_n<[0]_n$. Adding 1 on both sides gives $?<[1]_n$. Thus, a contradiction.
- Case 2: Let $[0]_n<[1]_n$. Then by (3), we have $[0]_n<[1]_n<[2]_n<...<[k-1]_n$. Then by (2), we have $[0]_n<[k-1]_n$. Adding 1 on both sides gives $[1]_n<?$. Thus a contradiction.

The above proof is using the hints that was given to me by my professor. What I am concerned on is how this gives a contradiction, since the question marks should be $k$s, but I am not sure how that is a contradiction? If the questions marks were 0s it would make sense to me, but I am not sure if that is correct.

Comment: As Robert said, change k's to n's.  Also, depending on the level of rigor demanded, you might be required to explicitly use induction rather than simply place ellipses to have the reader infer a pattern.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The $k$s should be $n$s.  You're proving (via repeated addition) that $[n-1]_n \lt [0]_n$ or $[0] \lt [n-1]_n$.  The point is that since addition is monotone, the fact that you can use addition to cycle from $[1]$ to $[0]$ means that $[1]$ can be neither less than nor greater than $[0]$, and since they're also not equal, we have our contradiction.

Comment: So it would be correct if I then had that $[1]_n<[n]_n$ for Case 2 gives a contradiction? Or would it become $[1]_n<[0]_n$?

Comment: $[1]_n \lt [n]_n = [0]_n$ gets you your contradiction.